# Node function runs before promise.then() completes.

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird

Shouldn't `foo` run after `refreshToken` is complete? Right now foo runs before `foo` is completed.

```
function refreshToken() {
    var tokenFile = path.join(__dirname, 'token-file.json');
    return fs.readFileAsync(tokenFile, {encoding: 'utf-8'})
        .then(function(tokenString) {
            token = JSON.parse(tokenString);
        }).catch(function(err) {
            console.log("No token-file.json file found. " .red +
                "Please complete for a new one." .red);
            createTokenFile();
        }); 
}
```

---

```
refreshToken();
foo();
```

Comment: That, my friend, is asynchronicity in action.

Comment: I am confused why it is async...I am returning a promise...which I think should complete first before the next function runs, correct?

Comment: Welcome to NodeJS. I hope you enjoy your stay - get used to this, as this is basically what NodeJS is developed around. Can the downvoters please explain why they took this to -1?

Comment: Since when does fs.readFileAsync return a promise?

Comment: it doesn't, I'm not actually sure if OP has run his code. I only just noticed that. `readFileAsync` is not a method.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/then-fs maybe, or some other module.

Comment: @KevinB: `fs.readFileAsync` is the [promisified](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promisification) version of `fs.readFile`, as constructed by Bluebird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Promises are just callbacks wrapped with an object, they are still asynchronous. You need to wrap your foo call with a .then()

```
refreshToken()
.then(foo)
```

or

```
refreshToken()
.then(function(res){
  foo()
})
```

The choice largely depends on how foo() is implemented.

Comment: In fact the `refreshToken` promise always resolves with `undefined`, so your two notations are equivalent (apart from the `return` and `arguments.length`)